Using WMIC to manage pagefile.sys doesn't actually enable it
I try to enable pagefile using wmic. Here's what I do:

To enable pagefile:


wmic pagefileset create name="p:\pagefile.sys"

Reply:
Instance creation successful.


To set it's size:


wmic pagefileset set name="p:\pagefile.sys",InitialSize=400,MaximumSize=400

Reply:
Updating property(s) of '\\WIN-QK1C5IBHU8C\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_PageFileSetting.Name="p:\\\\pagefile.sys"'
Property(s) update successful.


To test if everything went well


wmic pagefileset

Reply:
     Caption              Description            InitialSize  MaximumSize  Name              SettingID
p:\  '\pagefile.sys'      '\pagefile.sys' @ p:\  400          400          p:\\pagefile.sys  \pagefile.sys @ p:


To remove it


wmic pagefileset where name="p:\pagefile.sys" delete

Reply:
No Instance(s) Available.


So the last step should've removed it, but it can't, saying there's no [such] pagefile (No Instance Available). But Step 3 proves otherwise, isn't it? So for the further checks I open systempropertiesadvanced.exe to check the pagefile and here's what I see:

First it says my total pagefile amount is 0, then I press "Change..." and see my settings were apllied. But in a strange way: actually there's no pagefile in the system. I can tell it by empty P: drive. Also AIDA64 reports there's no paging files at all.

If I first set "No paging file" in that window, and then set the same amount manually, then it applies correctly.
Am I missing something? How should I use wmic to enable pagefile?
